# CCUserDefault flush, CFPreferences Background Sync Queue

Tags: ios, coco2d-x

We developed a game using cocos2dx framework. Our app crashed in following line (not all the time, around 1 in 20 times). 
Can you please help us to identify the issue.

```
CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault()->setIntegerForKey("NetWorth", netWorth);        
CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault()->flush();
```

crash log: 
Crashed: CFPreferences Background Sync Queue 
    EXC_BAD_ACCESS UNKNOWN at 0x006a5936 raw 
    0 CoreFoundation __CFTypeCollectionRetain + 7 
    1 CoreFoundation _CFArrayReplaceValues + 260 
    2 CoreFoundation _CFArrayReplaceValues + 260 
    .... 
    OilTycoon GamePlayScene.cpp line 11525 GamePlayScene::getNetWorth()

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a deprecated method.
Check out the sample in cpp-tests for correct usage.